# Marklogic REST API return only 2 app servers?

Tags: rest, marklogic

When I run the GET (using Postman):

http://localhost:8002/v1/rest-apis

It only returns 2 of the 8 or so app servers/databases that are running on my server. The admin user has all the permissions to do REST-API stuff, so I can't seem to figure out why they aren't all showing.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/v1/rest-apis

> Retrieve a list of **REST API instances**, including configuration details.

Not all application servers are REST-API servers.

> To use the REST Client API, you must create an instance of the API. The instance includes an HTTP App Server that exposes the API services, a URL rewriter, and the XQuery modules that implement the API.

[What Is an Instance?](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/service#id_15309)

> Before you can use the REST Client API, you must have access to an instance that consists of an HTTP App Server specially configured to handle REST Client API requests, a content database, and a modules database.

You can have HTTP appservers that haven't been [configured as a REST-API instance](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/service#id_12021). When you do that, it installs some additional configurations (such as HTTP rewriter and modules, in order to provide the functionality of the REST-API.

Without that, an HTTP application server is just an HTTP server, not a MarkLogic REST-API instance.

**If you want a list of all the MarkLogic application servers, not just the REST-API servers, then try the [/manage/v2/servers](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/manage/v2/servers) endpoint instead.**

http://localhost:8002/manage/v2/servers

Comment: That works!  One more question on the same theme... if I already created a HTTP server using the Admin console (or the ones created by Data Hub) can I add REST-API functionality to them?

Comment: I don't think there is anything exposed to configure an existing HTTP appserver. It's probably easiest to delete the existing HTTP server and re-create as REST-API.